# Re-Sending an email from the command line

Tags: mail, mailutils

i want to reproduce a mail related problem regarding a mail that is sent from a system i have no control over.
For this purpose i want to mimic this problematic email.

I have the exact mail as it was received as a text file (headers + base64 encoded body)
How can i send a very similar mail from one of our systems?

I tried

```
mail -s "Test" me@nowhere.net < mail.txt
```

But it puts the whole text file into the body.

thanks in advance
Jens

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC 5322 Internet Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) the body of the message starts after an empty line.

You can use `awk` to print everything in `mail.txt` after the first empty line, like this:

```
awk '/^$/,0' mail.txt
```

So you could do something like

```
awk '/^$/,0' mail.txt | mail -s "Test" me@nowhere.net
```

That, however, will start the output with an empty line. If you want to avoid that, use a slightly more complicated `awk` range:

```
awk 'p; !/./{p=0}/^$/{p=1}' mail.txt | mail -s "Test" me@nowhere.net
```

This last trick is one I picked up [here](https://backreference.org/2010/09/11/smart-ranges-in-awk/).

Comment: @SebastianStark I may have, yes. I did not test the full command.

Answer (score 0):

If the machine has the `sendmail` compatibility program installed (usually it should have it, this was tested with postfix installed), then you can use a command like this:

```
sendmail -i -f from@example.org to@example.org <test.mail
```

With `test.mail` looking like this for example:

```
From: from@example.org
To: to@example.org
Subject: Test
X-Spam-Flag: NO

some content
```

You will most likely not be able to reproduce too much of the original email, since many headers are only added or modified later by the mail server itself.